# Laravel: Scheduled commands execution: parallel or sequential?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-queue

I want to ask about command-line commands execution in Kernel.php.

I have multiple commands scheduled to run every 15 minutes.

Some of these commands take 5-8 minutes to process (fetching and analyzing statistics data from remote servers through API).

My question is - are all these commands executed in the same time and run in parallel, or they are executed one by one in a sequence?

As over time as I keep adding these commands it looks like it takes longer than it should, I'm trying to optimize the flow, so everything is finished on time.

Thanks for shedding some light over this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you setup multiple commands to run for example at 08:15 they will be executed one by one in sequence (tested in Laravel 5.1). So if first one takes 15 minutes, next one will start executing at 08:30 and not at 08:15.

What could you consider is doing this: in scheduler you should add jobs to queue and then they will be executed in same time depending on how many queue workers you set

Comment: But be careful when running multiple queue workers and (very) long running tasks. Depending on your queue setup it could happen that some jobs overtake others (of the same kind). It might be necessary to take additional precautions, if such behavior is inacceptable.

Comment: Thank you Marcin for your reply. Now I know why it takes so long. @namoshek: Yes some commands should follow in order, but as it runs periodically it's not a big deal. So what I could do is run these commands at 8:15, 8:16, 8:17...etc. so they all get launched OR follow the jobs queue procedure suggested by Marcin. Never used jobs before, I have to take a look at the docs first. Another way for the chained commands - not sure if possible would be to launch the next command when the previous finishes. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Basically, you just push the same job onto the queue again at the end of the job. But you will also need some sort of _initial trigger_, e.g. a console command. There are better solutions out there though.